# Back reference in negative lookback

Tags: php, regex

Starts with aa or bb. Ends with it (back reference). And has no it in the middle.

It is ok without "or" and back reference -- `aa.*?(?!aa).*?aa`
But it does not work with them:
`(aa|bb).*?(?!\1).*?\1`

```
echo preg_match("@(aa|bb).*?(?!\\1).*?\\1@", 'aaxxaaxaa'); // 1 ??
echo preg_match("@(aa|bb).*?(?!\\1).*?\\1@", 'aaxxxaa'); // 1
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Oh dint notice ``preg_match``!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your negative condition **for every character**.

```
(aa|bb)((?!\\1).)*\\1
```

You also need to add anchors.

```
^(aa|bb)((?!\\1).)*\\1$
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/mQxgG)